# How to convert a string into a list in Python?

Tags: python, string, list

How can I convert a variable with the value 10, like this
`variable = "10"`
, into a list from 10 to 0 like this:

`list = ["10", "9", "8", "7", "6", "5", "4", "3", "2", "1","0",]`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
# 1: Contvert str '10' to int.
# 2: Create range(10+1) -> [0,...10]
# 3: Reverse list to desired order with '[::-1]' -> [10, 9, ..., 0]
# 4: Convert all elements in 'list' to 'str' with 'map(str, ...)'
>>> list(map(str, range(int('10')+1)[::-1]))
['10', '9', '8', '7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1', '0']
```

Comment: Suggestion: Change `list(map(str, range(int('10')+1)))[::-1]` to `list(map(str, range(int('10')+1)[::-1]))`. The latter reverses the original `range` (with `O(1)` work; it just replaces it with a new `range` object with reversed definition), your original code reverses the final `list` (with `O(n)` work, since it has to shallow copy it to a new `list` in reverse). For 10 elements it makes little difference, but for 10,000,000 it would save a *lot* of unnecessary peak memory consumption and reversing work.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution (that skips `[::-1]`):

```py
variable = "10"

out = list(map(str, range(int(variable), -1, -1)))
print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
['10', '9', '8', '7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1', '0']
```

Comment: Note: There is no meaningful cost to using `[::-1]` *if* it's applied to the `range` object (*before* looping over it to make some other object). `range`s being abstract sequences, the cost of reversing them is `O(1)` (where a reverse on any concrete sequence would be `O(n)`); I typically prefer making a forward `range` and `[::-1]`ing it simply because `range(10)[::-1]` is more understandable than `range(9, -1, -1)` (I really hate having to give an end of `-1` to mean `0` is the true end, exclusive end points feel weird when the goal is to reach `0`).

Comment: @ShadowRanger TIL something new :) You're right, `range(9, -1, -1)` isn't that elegant as `range(10)[::-1]`

Comment: They want to include the 10, though, so it's rather `range(n, -1, -1)` vs `range(n + 1)[::-1]` and that `+ 1` isn't pretty, either.

Comment: @KellyBundy: Yeah, it's not perfect either way, but `range(n + 1)[::-1]` is still prettier to me. Obviously some personal preference comes in here. There's no strong reason to prefer either, but if you're going the reversing after the fact route, you want to apply it to the `range` up-front (where the cost is effectively zero), not to the final `list` (where you pay increasing costs relative to length).

Comment: @ShadowRanger With exclusive upper end, I usually do prefer reversing an ascending range. But with inclusive upper end, I much prefer the direct version. I don't like adding 1, and I like the directness of saying "start with (what I really want to start with)". Adding 1 *and* reversing is *two* steps away from saying what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a list comprehension.
First convert the string to int.

```py
print([str(i) for i in range(int('10'),-1,-1)])
# Which prints
['10', '9', '8', '7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1', '0']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `map` and `__reversed__`:

```
variable = "10"
print(list(map(str, range(int(variable)+1).__reversed__())))
```

Or "slower" ones using `sorted`:

```
variable = "10"
print([str(x) for x in sorted(range(int(variable)+1), reverse=True)])
```